# React Filtering Approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such data:

```
created: "2017-11-04T18:48:46.250Z"
episode: (51) ['https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/1', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/2', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/3', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/4', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/5', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/6', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/7', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/8', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/9', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/11', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/12', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/13', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/14', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/15', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/16', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/17', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/18', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/19', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/20', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/21', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/22', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/23', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/24', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/25', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/26', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/27', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/28', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/29', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/30', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/31', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/32', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/33', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/34', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/35', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/36', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/37', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/38', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/39', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/40', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/41', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/42', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/43', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/44', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/45', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/46', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/47', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/48', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/49', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/50', 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/51']
gender: "Male"
id:1
image:"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg"
location: {name: 'Citadel of Ricks', url: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3'}
name:"Rick Sanchez"
origin: {name: 'Earth (C-137)', url: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1'}
species:"Human"
status:"Alive"
type:""
url:"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1"
```

And I have like 800 records like that + have 3 filters where I can find `name, status, gender`

so I created:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (name || gender || status) {
      setFilteredData(characters.filter((character) => character.name.includes(name)) && character.status === status && character.gender === gender)
    }
  }, [name, gender, status])
```

And it is fine only when I have 3 values of these filters, but how can I change it and not add let say gender filter here when the filter is empty? Because right now I have `gender = '', status = '', name = ''` as default filters and it doesn't find any records.

How can it be done?

Comment: Note that asking for the "best" approach is off-topic on Stack Overflow as it permits any answer (including spam), rather than what you want, which are ones that work, and are good according to facts and experience. I've modified your question to simply ask how to get it done, which means that no one can claim theirs is right because it's the "best".

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, that's because some people on Stack Overflow are unable to understand the intentions of a question. I guess hard skills negate soft ones for some. "Best approach" is often quite clear.

Comment: @RoboRobok Why not just ask how to do something? I mean, you can continue to denigrate and belittle others if that makes you feel better about yourself, but it seems much easier to simply ask the question in a shorter, simpler way.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I experienced it dozens of times here already. And it's funny, because many of the most upvoted questions on Stack Overflow use the same, vague and best approach-seeking style. Don't focus on how the question is asked.

Comment: @RoboRobok Don't focus on how the question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `filteredData` is a pure function of state, it shouldn't be state at all itself, but you should use `useMemo` instead.

Then, move your filtering logic into a separate pure function, and hook them up:

```
function characterMatchesFilter(character, name, gender, status) {
  if (name && !character.name.includes(name)) return false;
  if (gender && character.gender !== gender) return false;
  if (status && character.status !== status) return false;
  return true;
}

function RickAndMortyVerse() {
  const characters = []; // Your data here...
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [gender, setGender] = useState(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const filteredCharacters = React.useMemo(
    () => characters.filter((character) => characterMatchesFilter(character, name, gender, status)),
    [characters, name, gender, status],
  );
  // TODO: add UI to modify the filters.
  return (
    <>
      {filteredCharacters.map((c) => (
        <div key={c.name}>{c.name}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works great! Very creative is your function `characterMatchesFilter`

Comment: I have one more question. Maybe something different => Styling / animation on updating data. When I have less data then I don't have the animation, but when is from less to more then I have. How could we have animation on filtering always?

Comment: I just added `animation: showUp 1s`

Answer (score 0):

```js
(character.name.includes(name)) || name === '') && (character.status === status || status === '') && (character.gender === gender || gender === '')
```

I would just adjust the filter callback to return true for each of your and statements if the filter is the empty string.